# How do I generate daily reports in Microsoft Reporting Services 2008 R2?

Tags: reporting-services

I have the database in sql 2008.  In this database daily some data is being inserted.  I have to generate the report automatically without giving date i.e today is 10-10-2012.  I have to view the report of 10-10-2012 on 11-10-2012 daily. It should happen automatically i.e Previous date  entry should generate on current date without changing dates daily. Whether it is possible in SSRS report or we have to change in stored procedures please give the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  I just did it.

Two options:

- 1 Specify the report parameters (dates) and give them default parameters.  (Use a formula - hint, look for DateAdd in the formula editor)
- 2 set the query using DateAdd in SQL

When you've got the report, create a subscription.

How to do all this is covered in the documentation, available from Help on the SSRS website, or by pushing F1 in the Report builder.

Comment: Glad to help.  It took me a while to figure it out myself.  I'm pretty new to SSRS, and I had just happened to figure this out last week.